# Existe uma palavra para indicar "aniversário" de um mês?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Tenho visto [seguidamente](https://www.google.com.br/?q=mesvers%C3%A1rio) (pelo menos em PT-BR) o uso da palavra *mesversário* para indicar quando um bebê completa 1 mês (ou subseqüentes meses) de vida. Estranhamente esta palavra não existe nos dicionários que procurei tais como o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mesvers%C3%A1rio), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=mesvers%E1rio) e [Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/pesquisa.php?q=mesvers%E1rio). Seu uso parece ser uma adaptação de *aniversário*, removendo o prefixo *ani-* que indica ano. Assim imagino que falantes do idioma infiram seu significado ao ouvi-la.

A título de informação, uma pergunta semelhante foi feita no [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255310/word-request-for-equivalent-of-anniversary-but-for-time-period-of-a-month) e a [resposta de lá](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/255315/139185) é usar a expressão *aniversário de 1 mês, aniversário de 2 meses*, o que considero estranho, já que *aniversário* implicitamente se refere a ’1 ano’.

Afinal, existe uma palavra consagrada no Português para indicar o anivesário de 1 mês? De bônus, caso não exista, *mesversário* seria compreendido em PT-PT?

Comment: Nunca ouvi tal coisa em Portugal. Aqui costuma-se dizer "faz 1 mês", "a festa de 1 mês" sem associar qualquer tipo de palavra. Acho até que até aos 2 anos de idade se usam somente meses "a minha filha já tem 18 meses".

Comment: "aniversário de 1 mês" soa mal realmente, mas "aniversário de 3 anos" também soa mal.

Comment: Eu já ouvi, em Portugal, a versão `mesiversário`.

Comment: @ANeves sério? Não fazia ideia que isso se usa por cá.

Comment: @ANeves Achei no dicionário informal tanto [mesiversario](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/mesivers%C3%A1rio/) quanto [mesversario](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/mesvers%C3%A1rio/), mas nunca ouvi _mesiversário_ aqui no BR.

Comment: No google achei isso "kit mensário c/ body new born de brinde", outra forma de inventar palavras, já que mensário é uma publicação mensal. Nunca ouvi nenhuma delas, mas deve ser um jeito de comemorar os meses de vida dos filhos de maneira especial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontrei na net quatro equivalentes mensais a *aniversário*: ***mesversário, mesiversário, mensiversário*** e ***mensário***. As três primeiras não vêm nos dicionários: nem nos online, nem no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) ou dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001); *mensário* vem, mas apenas com o significado de ‘publicação mensal’ (analogamente a *anuário, semanário, diário*) ou ‘relativo à mesa’ [(Periberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mens%C3%A1rio).

Mas qualquer destas palavras já foi usada no sentido pretendido, com maior ou menor frequência, no Brasil e em Portugal. Eu nunca tinha encontrado nenhuma delas, mas creio que qualquer português, em contexto, as compreenderia. Ficam aqui os números da busca no Google (não tenho inteira confiança na triagem por país do Google):

**Resultados da busca no Google**

```
                                     Brasil      Portugal
Mesversário (triagem Google)           158          44
Mesiversário (triagem Google)           38          35
Mensário (triagem manual)               64           5
Mensiversário (triagem manual)          14           9
```

***Mensiversário***  tem um cognato iglês, *mensiversary*, que foi também sugerido [nesta resposta no ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255310/word-request-for-equivalent-of-anniversary-but-for-time-period-of-a-month/255313#255313) e consta do [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mensiversary). É a menos usada das três palavras, mas é sob outros pontos de vista a que tem mais argumentos a seu favor.

É formada a partir do latim por analogia com *aniversário*. Diz o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) que *aniversário* vem do latim:

> *anniversarius,a,um* ‘que vem, que chega, que volta, que se faz a cada ano’; de *annus,i* ‘ano’ e rad. de *versum*, supino de *verto,is,ti,versum, vertere* ‘voltar, virar’

Ora, [Iris Gardini justifica](http://irisgardinocomunicacao.blogspot.pt/2015/02/ha-dois-meses-faz-dois-meses.html) ***mensiversário*** exatamente da mesma maneira:

> *mens, mensis* (latim) = mês
>
> versum, supino do verbo *verto,is,ti,versum,vertĕre* = voltar, virar; suceder-se no tempo

Depois, ***menisversário*** tem ilustres pergaminhos: ao que consegui apurar, nasceu a 5 de Julho de 1932 em Itaguara, Minas Gerais, pela pena do escritor brasileiro João Guimarães Rosa, numa carta a seu irmão Oswaldo, publicada pela filha do escritor, Vilma Guimarães Rosa em *Relembramentos: João Guimarães Rosa, Meu Pai*, 1983 (aqui numa [edição de 20014](https://books.google.pt/books?id=a_D-AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT315&dq=%22justamente%20no%20dia%20do%20d%C3%A9cimo%20terceiro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifvard4tnNAhUCeD4KHXmLAFYQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22justamente%20no%20dia%20do%20d%C3%A9cimo%20terceiro%22&f=false); scrolando para cima, vêem o *fac simile* do manuscrito original):

> *Itaguara, 5-VII-932*
>
> Oswaldo
>
> Recebi hoje a sua carta, justamente no dia do décimo terceiro *mensiversário* da Vilma, que trocou também hoje os seus primeiros tres passinhos sem apoio alheio.

Answer (score 2):

***Mesversário*** é muito comum no Brasil. Já vi pessoas também utilizando ***mensário***, mas gosto mais da outra versão.

Fontes:

- [Diconário Informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/mesvers%C3%A1rio/)
- [Significados](https://www.significados.com.br/mensario/)

Comment: Mesmo com as referências online eu não conhecia essas palavras, ao menos nunca as ouvi sendo usadas em pt_BR. Você saberia me dizer em quais regiões elas são muito utilizadas?

Comment: Sou do Rio de Janeiro. Mesversário é bastante utilizado. O que não vejo usarem é mensário, que até já vi, mas muito raramente.

Comment: Sou de São Paulo e nunca tinha ouvido.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas mais um neologismo (nenhuma linguagem é estanque); que seja bem vindo. Acho mais adequado *mesiversário* pois seria análogo a *ani + versário*.

Comment: Não seria equivalente mais a "anoi versário"?

Answer (score -2):

Bem. Já pesquisei, e nenhuma dessas palavras existe. Não com esse significado! Então o certo é *comemoração de x meses*.

Comment: Newton, bem-vindo à comunidade. Conviria que explicasses que pesquisa foi essa que fizeste e qual é o teu critério para a existência de uma palavra. Que significa para ti uma palavra existir ou não existir?