# O que distingue uma mentira carioca de uma simples mentira comum?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças, português-brasileiro

Andava eu à procura de [*mensiversário*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/existe-uma-palavra-para-indicar-anivers%C3%A1rio-de-um-m%C3%AAs) no Houaiss, quando me deparei com a ***mentira carioca***, que o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) explica assim:

> *s. f. B BA RJ* **1** afirmação falsa ou qualquer coisa feita com a intenção de enganar; mentira **2** *RJ* biscoito de povilho, leve e crocante, em forma de bastão ou rosca; peta

Esta explicação deixou-me curioso. É verdade que «coisa feita com a intenção de enganar» é diferente de ‘simples mentira’; mas «afirmação falsa [...] com intenção de enganar» já tem menos diferença; mas que *mentira carioca* possa ser simplesmente usado no lugar de *mentira* é que me parece estranho. Especialmente que seja usado assim no próprio Rio de Janeiro! Ou será que é no estado mas apenas fora da cidade?

Resumindo: falando-se de afirmações falsas, qual é a diferença entre *mentira carioca* e *mentira*? Podem dar alguns exemplos de uso? Quão comum é esta expressão? É usada neste sentido pelos próprios cariocas?

Comment: Mentira é como é chamando um tipo de biscoito muito comum por aqui. Esse termo quase não é mais usado. Ninguém chama biscoito de povilho de mentira, chamam de biscoioto de vento, biscoito de nada (talvez daí vem o termo mentira, do fato do biscoito quase não ter densidade).

Comment: @EdmilsonJunior: Seu comentário poderia ser a resposta

Comment: Opa desculpe! Era uma resposta minha, mas foi convertida em comentário por um moderador @Luciano

Comment: De qualquer forma, não existe mentira carioca em se trantando de "falsa informação. Talvez possa até existir fora do Rio de Janeiro, constituindo algum regionalismo que resalte alguma característica percebida do carioca, a qual nem nós cariocas nos damos conta. O dicionário pode talvez conter algum erro de impressão que levou equivocadamente a tal diferenciação.

Comment: @Edmilson, o dicionário Houaiss diz que existe, na Baía e Rio de Janeiro. A minha surpresa, que manifestei na pergunta, foi precisamente que *mentira carioca* fosse usado pelos próprios cariocas.

Comment: Eu vi, entendi o texto do dicionário de outra forma. Achei mal escrito. Afinal, dicionários podem conter erros também. Em fim, não seria o primeiro problema com este dicionário [wiki](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicion%C3%A1rio_Houaiss_da_L%C3%ADngua_Portuguesa).

Comment: @Edmilson, até pode ser um engano deles. Seria bom tirar isso a limpo. O problema relatado na Wikipédia não é erro do Houaiss, é uma acusação que Ministério Público fez ao Houaiss em 2012 e que o tribunal em 2014 julgou sem mérito. Não sei se houve desenvolvimentos posteriores. É problema é do artigo da  Wikipédia, que não conclui a história.

Answer (score 1):

Essa pergunta pode ter duas respostas diferentes.
Segundo o dicionário Michaelis, mentira também é um tipo de biscoito (item 7)

> mentira men·ti·ra sf 1 Ato ou efeito de mentir; cantiga, fraude,
>   pomada. 2 Afirmação que se opõe à verdade; informação enganosa ou
>   controvertida; enredo, moca. 3 Costume ou hábito de contar mentiras. 4
>   Aquilo que dá falsa ideia. 5 O que ilude. 6 Opinião sem fundamento. 7
>   REG (RJ), CUL Pequeno biscoito redondo e achatado, feito com massa de
>   pão de ló; mentirinha. 8 REG (MG), CUL Pastel sem recheio. 9 COLOQ
>   Mancha de cor branca nas unhas; leuconiquia.

Já a mentira-carioca, retirando do mesmo dicionário, é um biscoite de polvilho.

> mentira-carioca men·ti·ra-ca·ri·o·ca sf 1 REG (BA, RJ) Dito mentiroso
>   com o objetivo de enganar. 2 REG (RJ), CUL Biscoito leve, de massa de
>   polvilho, semelhante a um bastão ou rosca; peta.

Mas se pegarmos o primeiro significado da Mentira-Carioca, onde está dizendo claramente com o objetivo de enganar, concluo que podemos mentir sem o objetivo real de querer enganar. Para suportar essa minha ideia, vou buscar a definição de mentira da [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/mentira):

> men.ti.ramẽˈtirɐ nome feminino
>   1.    acto ou efeito de mentir, de faltar à verdade
>   2.    afirmação contrária à verdade, feita com a intenção de enganar; engano propositado
>   3.    aquilo que é falso ou enganador
>   4.    erro de juízo, interpretação ou percepção; ilusão

Assim, posso estar mentindo por um *erro de juízo* e sem o objetivo claro de querer enganar alguém.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta está na sua própria pergunta. A mentira carioca é o biscoito de polvilho, apenas mais um apelido para o biscoito.

[Veja esta pesquisa no Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=biscoito%20de%20polvilho&rct=j)

Ja mentira é qualquer coisa dita com intuito de enganar.

Comment: Entendo que sua resposta diz o mesmo que o Houaiss menciona, mas não vi aqui a explicação entre o que distingue uma mentira carioca de uma comum. Poderias elaborar melhor?

Answer (score -1):

Brasil é um país grande, portanto sua cultura e língua varia muito dependendo do local.
Mentira em todo o país é de fato algo dito com intuito de enganar, omitir verdade...
No Rio de Janeiro em específico, a palavra mentira não é usada, e sim o caô, que tem o mesmo significado.
Geralmente o caô é acompanhado do verbo mandar;

> "Ele mentiu."
>
> "Ele mandou um caô."
>
> "Ele é mentiroso."
>
> "Ele é caôseiro."

Caô ainda que um termo coloquial, é amplamente usado e reconhecido pela língua portuguesa.

Mentira carioca é uma expressão que reflete uma mentira mal-contada, uma vez que os cariocas não usam o termo "mentira" e sim caô.

Comment: *"... os cariocas não usam o termo "mentira" e sim caô."*  Tem certeza? Caô é gíria, não tem base nenhuma os cariocas não usarem a palavra "mentira".

Comment: Acho que "mentira carioca" é uma expressão muitíssimo mais antiga do que "caô". "Mentira carioca" está nos dicionários. Quando morei no RJ - de 1963 a 1976, "caô" ainda não tinha sido cunhada...

Comment: Concordo com o @BrunoLopes. A palavra mentira é usada no Rio de Janeiro, mesmo que a gíria caô também o seja. Exemplo: música ["Me usa", do Bonde do Tigrão](https://www.vagalume.com.br/bonde-do-tigrao/me-usa.html) (banda de funk carioca).